# .NET trouble when using doubles

Tags: .net, floating-accuracy

In .NET, when I subtract 1.35 from 1.35072 it shows .000719999999. How could I get .00072 when using a `double`?

```
TOTKILO.Text = KILO.Text * TOUCH.Text * 0.01;    //here 1.35072
TextBox10.Text = TextBox9.Text * TextBox8.Text * 0.01; //here 1.35
K = Val(TOTKILO.Text) - Val(TextBox10.Text);  //here it shows 0.00719999
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear - please can you try and edit your question to make it easier to understand what it is you are trying to do and what you are having problems with.

Comment: @eldarerathis You should get a medal or something!

Comment: @Kragen: I'll gladly accept one if they're being distributed, but only if I get to stand on a nifty podium, too.

Comment: Ha, wow, just checked out @eldarerathis's mighty edit... I wish you could upvote edits!

Comment: Wow, eldarerathis's edit really saved this question. Casting final re-open vote...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on what you're really asking.

If you want to round to five decimal places, you can just do:

```
double x = 1.35072;
double y = 1.35;
double z = Math.Round(x - y, 5); // 0.00072
```

If, on the other hand, your goal is to always get precise results from adding/subtracting decimal numbers, use the `decimal` type instead of `double` since it is inherently a base-10 type (as opposed to a base-2 type) and can therefore represent numbers expressed in *decimal* form precisely.

```
decimal x = 1.35072M;
decimal y = 1.35M;
decimal z = x - y; // 0.00072M
```

Answer (score 0):

Doubles and floating points are always represented with a varying degree of precision than what we visualize them to be. Always round up the values to few decimals and then check the answers.

Additional details are in *[How To Work Around Floating-Point Accuracy/Comparison Problems](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/69333)*.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, you almost never actually need a `double`. Nearly all the time a `decimal` (`System.Decimal`) works for what you need, and it is an exact number, not a floating point representation, so you'll never have these rounding problems.

Comment: Never have rounding problems? So `1M - (1M / 3M)` will give me an exact result? (Just giving you a hard time ;))